# XPath questions for Selenium Webdriver C# to locate search result on webpage

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, automated-tests

I am new to Selenium and trying to implement Webjet (www.webjet.com.au) to complete a search process and a flight booking after the search result. However I had difficulties while locating search results , I inspected the link in firebug however it is wrapped in div/ and confused me. I tried Linked Text too but it wouldn't work.

Edit: The element I am trying to locate is the flight fare (e.g:$97),The html code from Firebug is shown below:

```
<div class="span1 matrix-price multifare">
<div>
<span class=" without-baggage baggage fare-select OneWay Morning oneway" data-price="97" data-flight-group-no="216" data-flight-halfreturn-token="" data-fare-id="1000072" data-baggage-id="JQ.BGNO" data-original-title="">$97</span>
```

The XPath for this element is 

`.//[@id='flight-matrixes-wrapper']/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[10]/div[3]/div[1]/span`

Different results will be generated depends on the flight search criteria, I looked up from previous examples and tried to use

`driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//[contains(text(),'$')]/descendant::*)")).Click();`  but  not very sure.

Comment: Can you post your code?  It's hard to tell what's going on without seeing the HTML, and I can't easily figure out what page you're actually trying to perform the action on.

Comment: this `/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div)"` looks a bit funny

Comment: @Noctis, this is the XPath i got from Firepath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a search on the given web site and based on that I think following xpath might be helpful

```
//div[contains(@class,'matrix-price')]//div//span[text()='$328']
```

If you know the expected price(here $328) you can directly use above xpath , or else you could  use below to get all pricing shows on the grid

```
//div[contains(@class,'matrix-price')]//div//span[contains(text(),'$')]
```

Anyway if you are going to click a specific price you need to know the exact price you want to click

**Additional Notes**

01) Above xpaths are given assuming you are refering to the pricing grid similar to the attached image!

[image]

02) Make sure that you are waiting enough until the grid is properly populated

03) I have used Fire Finder to build the xpath, fire finder highlights elements matches with given xpath (as shown in the attached image as well )

***Code Snippet for Waiting***

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement Elem = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
{
    return d.FindElement(By.Class("matrix-price"));
});
```

You could wait for the exact Pricing element instead of above . You could increases the time span(in above code) if 10 seconds not enough

Comment: Thanks a lot Dasun, the result elements can be highlighted correctly now. I have got another question about that when I try to use      'driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class,'matrix-price')]//div//span[text()='$99']")).Click()'; [/code] There is a warning message saying element not visible or may not be interact with , I have set the 10 seconds waiting time though. Any ideas? @DasunB

Comment: I think you could implement a "wait for element" code here . I ll update the answer with a code snippet

Please refer - http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

for additional information - This is where I have taken the code snippet

If my answers solves your problem , please mark it as the correct answer 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clich here:

Try:

```
 driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@class='span1 matrix-price multifare']")).Click();
```

If you want to clich here:
$97

Try:

```
 driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@class=' without-baggage baggage fare-select OneWay Morning oneway']")).Click();
```

I only know this, because i'm new in this

Comment: Thanks a lot @Lion6 , I have tried a exactly same code , but it won't locate on the link element

Comment: I'm so sorry, and now sorry for the stupid next question: from here exactly which button is: http://www.webjet.com.au/ the green button with the text "Search Flights"?

Comment: holly molly ... why don't you just edit your answer instead of creating multiple ones ?

Comment: Oh, I have not thinked in that, it's my first time answering here, gracias. ah, have you any idea to solve the problem of the code whicht Billyuatbcs is looking for?

Comment: :D thank you for helping me anyway , "Search Flights"can be find by By.Id("flight-search-button")  @Lion6